# Dropdown menu button in tcl/tk

Tags: user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit

Is there any way  to create a drop down toolbar button(Like Paste button in MS Word) using Tcl/TK?.I have googled a lot but nothing found.Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a [`menubutton`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/menubutton.htm) and a [`menu`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/menu.htm), probably with `radiobutton` entries if I've understood which UI element in Word you're talking about. (Or maybe a [`ttk::menubutton`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_menubutton.htm) and `menu`.) Now, if you're doing something very simple with it then you can make do with just [`tk_optionMenu`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/optionMenu.htm) as a way to combine those commands, but that's just a simple procedure; if you're doing something complicated with the menu, it's probably easier to write it yourself or at least to get the code for `tk_optionMenu` and to customise it how you want it to work.

The [source code](http://core.tcl.tk/tk/artifact/9745c83eec856560) for `tk_optionMenu` isn't very long; I'll paste the non-comment parts of it here:

```
proc ::tk_optionMenu {w varName firstValue args} {
    upvar #0 $varName var

    if {![info exists var]} {
        set var $firstValue
    }
    menubutton $w -textvariable $varName -indicatoron 1 -menu $w.menu \
            -relief raised -highlightthickness 1 -anchor c \
            -direction flush
    menu $w.menu -tearoff 0
    $w.menu add radiobutton -label $firstValue -variable $varName
    foreach i $args {
        $w.menu add radiobutton -label $i -variable $varName
    }
    return $w.menu
}
```

You probably want to pay attention to how the `menubutton` and `menu` are connected to each other. `ttk::menubutton` is *mostly* a drop-in replacement for `menubutton`, except for different look-and-feel configuration options.

Comment: how if use this code? I tried to read, and understand the tutorial you suggested from the source. But I couldn't make him spin. Can you tell you how to do it to spin?

Comment: Why there isn't a ttk::menu widget? There is a ttk replacement for almost all the other widgets.